# Issue with scala-maven-plugin

Tags: java, scala, maven

I try to build the Maven project that has both Scala and Java classes:

```
sudo mvn clean -X install -DskipTests
```

How to solve this issue?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile
>   (scala-compile-first) on project spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10:
>   Execution scala-compile-first of goal
>   net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed.
>   CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile
>   (scala-compile-first) on project spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10:
>   Execution scala-compile-first of goal
>   net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed.   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
>   scala-compile-first of goal
>   net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed.   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: Compilation failed   at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:105)  at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)    at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)    at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
>     at
>   sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
>     at
>   sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
>     at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)    at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)    at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)    at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)   at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)    at
>   sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)   at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
>     at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:184)   at
>   com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:164)    at
>   sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:92)
>     at
>   scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:303)
>     at
>   scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
>     at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo
>   (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)

`<build>` part of pom.xml file:

> ```
> <build>
>     <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
>     <resources>
>         <resource>
>             <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>             <filtering>true</filtering>
>         </resource>
>         <resource>
>             <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
>             <filtering>true</filtering>
>         </resource>
>     </resources>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
>             </configuration>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>copy-resources</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
>             <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.2.0</version>
>             <configuration>
>         <!--<recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>-->
>         <args>
>             <arg>-target:jvm-1.7</arg>
>         </args>
>         <javacArgs>
>             <javacArg>-source</javacArg>
>             <javacArg>1.7</javacArg>
>             <javacArg>-target</javacArg>
>             <javacArg>1.7</javacArg>
>         </javacArgs>
>     </configuration>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <id>scala-compile</id>
>             <phase>process-resources</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>compile</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>         <execution>
>             <id>scala-test-compile</id>
>             <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>testCompile</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>     <configuration>
>         <source>1.7</source>
>         <target>1.7</target>
>     </configuration>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <phase>compile</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>compile</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> org.eclipse.m2e
>                       lifecycle-mapping
>                       1.0.0
>                       
>                           
>                               
>                                   
>                                       
>                                           
>                                               net.alchim31.maven
>                                           
>                                           
>                                               scala-maven-plugin
>                                           
>                                           
>                                               [3.1.6,)
>                                           
>                                           
>                                               compile
>                                               testCompile

Update (dependencies section):

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
      <artifactId>flume-ng-sdk</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Guava is excluded to avoid its use in this module. -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!--
          Exclude libthrift since the flume poms seem to confuse sbt, which fails to find the
          dependency.
        -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
          <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
      <artifactId>flume-ng-core</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
          <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- Add Guava in test scope since flume actually needs it. -->
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!--
        Netty explicitly added in test as it has been excluded from
        Flume dependency (to avoid runtime problems when running with
        Spark) but unit tests need it. Version of Netty on which
        Flume 1.4.0 depends on is "3.4.0.Final" .
      -->
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you show dependencies section?

Comment: @Roman: See my update.

Comment: @Roman: There is also another file called `dependency-reduced-pom.xml`. May it produce the problem mentioned in the thread?